# ruby: No such file or directory -- puts (LoadError) on mac

Tags: ruby

I'm just starting to learn ruby.

I type in the console `ruby puts "Hello World !"`

and it's return me 
`ruby: No such file or directory -- puts (LoadError)`

I'm working on Mavericks ( macbook pro )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ruby executable expects a file name, e.g.:

```
$ ruby test.rb
```

`ruby puts` tries to load a file named `puts`, resulting in the error message.

Use the `-e` switch to evaluate a single line / command:

```
$ ruby -e 'puts "Hello World"'
Hello World
```

Comment: I understand, but how can i define a file ?
Sorry for thoses stupid questions but i'm a novice and it's obscure for me. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Kéryh you can create and edit files with a text editor. I think [Atom](https://atom.io) would a good choice. There's a tutorial [10 Minutes to Your First Ruby Application](http://neurogami.com/content/10_minutes_to_your_first_Ruby_app) covering the basics.

Comment: I work with Sublimtext for integration or wordpress development. 
My question was how to link my file to my console.
Thanks for your link and your help, i also found a french tutorial 
which made ​​me understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using Mac OS X open up Terminal and type irb, then hit enter.

```
➜  ~  irb
irb(main):001:0> puts "Hello World !"
Hello World !
=> nil
irb(main):002:0>
```

IRB stands for “interactive ruby” and is a tool to interactively execute ruby expressions read from the standard input.

Comment: It works, thanks.
Can you explain me why it doesn't work with the "ruby puts" command ?